wildfly22 integration with keycloak 403 forbidden error
I have an application integrated with keycloak. THe application runs on wildfly server. I use web.xml to authenticate keycloak(as Login config). Apart from that i use keycloak.json file, where i define the keycloak realm settings in application. When i invoke the application pages, the keycloak login pages opens, after entereing the credentials, it comes back to wildfly with 403 forbidden error.
I aslo tried "disable-trust-manager": true in keycloak.json
that's also not working .
when its try to hit my index.jsp after pressing login its getting 403 Forbidden error. http://localhost:9185/gui/index.jsp.
Please help me in resolving the issue

It's very difficult to determine the issue from what you've described.  Would there be any way to create a small example that shows the problem?

for my case the problem was I wasn't assigned the role to the user, which I have give in my web.xml for authentication. after assigning it I'm able to login
